# the_content after all shortcodes are parsed

Tags: plugin-development, the-content

I am creating a WordPress Plugin for WordPress directory.

How can I get `the_content()` after applying all the shortcodes that are presents in `the_content`?

Let me explain:

My plugin will be used in multiple themes and websites; and users will add some shortcodes in their posts or pages. I want my plugin to work after these shortcodes are parsed, and then use the content for my plugin as input.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a filter perhaps?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_the_content_filter', 20 );

function wpse_the_content_filter( $content ) {
   // Do whatever you want with the $content
   return $content;
}
```

Filtering 'the_content' will pass the post or page content through a function of your choice.

Just make sure to run it late (e.g. 20) and return the contents so they can be displayed.

More information here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 3):

## First rule:

When used within theme's template files (i.e. WordPress loop), `the_content()` will by default return the content after applying all the shortcodes.

## Second rule:

If you have any custom shortcode, you must have shortcode handler function applied with [`add_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/) (obviously). Otherwise your own custom shortcodes will not work.

## Third rule:

If your plugin's content related function is running independently from [`the loop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and you want to retrieve the content using custom query, then to apply the shortcodes in the content, you may use `do_shortcode` function. Like:

```
$content = do_shortcode( $content );
```

***or,*** you may use `the_content` filter for the same purpose:

```
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
```

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/173844/111485) you'll find a similar discussion.